# How do you create an interpreted function in SBCL?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I want to create an interpreted function definition, not a compiled one.

[SBCL manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Interpreter) says :

> Variable: *evaluator-mode* [sb-ext] : Toggle between different evaluator
>   implementations. If set to :compile, an implementation of eval that
>   calls the compiler will be used. If set to :interpret, an interpreter
>   will be used.

So, I try to create a BAR function (which does not exist) :

```
(let ((sb-ext::*evaluator-mode* :interpret))
  (defun bar (x) (+ x 1)))
```

But then, I check, and BAR is already compiled :

```
CL-USER> (compiled-function-p #'bar)
T
```

So, how do you create an interpreted version of BAR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The let form in your question only sets the evaluator mode at runtime. By then, the function has already been compiled.

You need to set it at load time and also make sure to `load` the file instead of compiling then loading it.

Try this:

In `your-file.lisp`:

```
;; at load time, set evaluator mode to interpret (before bar definition is met)
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :execute)
  (setf sb-ext::*evaluator-mode* :interpret))

;;define your interpreted function
(defun bar (x)
  (+ x 1))

;; set evaluator back to compile mode (optional)
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :execute)
  (setf sb-ext::*evaluator-mode* :compile))

;;check if bar is a compiled function
(print (compiled-function-p #'bar)) ;;prints NIL
```

Then load it with `(load "your-file.lisp")` (this doesn't compile the file first).

Answer (score 0):

I think that `*evaluator-mode*` is pretty inherently a global variable.  For instance, if you do this:

```
> (setf sb-ext:*evaluator-mode* ':interpret)
:interpret
> (setf (symbol-function 'bar)
        (lambda (x) x))
#<interpreted-function nil {10026E7E2B}>
> (compiled-function-p #'bar)
nil
```

you get an interpreted function.  But if you do this:

```
> (setf sb-ext:*evaluator-mode* ':compile)
:compile
> (setf (symbol-function 'bar)
        (let ((sb-ext:*evaluator-mode* ':interpret))
          (lambda (x) x)))
#<function (lambda (x)) {52C3687B}>
> (compiled-function-p #'bar)
t
```

You don't.  My take on this, which may be wrong, is that the value which is in effect at the start of each top-level form is what counts: once the system has decided that it's going to use the compiling-evaluator for a form then it can't change its mind.

And note that there is a complicated definition of 'top-level form', and in particular that when processing a file then in a form like

```
(let (...)
  (x ...))
```

then `(x ...)` is not a top-level form.